# OR logical operator within an if statement returning truthy when falsey

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

```
function doesItStartWithJ (name) {
    if(name.charAt(0) === "J" || "j") {
        return "Hello " + name + "!";
    } else {
        return "Who are you?";
    }
}
```

I was trying to use the code above to solve a problem but kept getting errors on test cases with lowercase names and figured out that I had to fix my if conditional to make the code work, as such:

```
function doesItStartWithJ (name) {
    if(name.charAt(0) === "J" || name.charAt(0) === "j") {
        return "Hello " + name + "!";
    } else {
        return "Who are you?";
    }
}
```

I figured that I had to use the charAt method again for the lowercase cases. 
Why does this not work

```
name.charAt(0) === "J" || "j"
```

but works with

```
name.charAt(0) === "J" || name.charAt(0) === "j"
```

???

Comment: `"j"` itself is an expression whose result can be truthy or falsey, just like all values in JS. So `"j"` is always truthy, so it's like you're doing `(name.charAt(0) === "J") || true`, which of course will always result in `true`.

Comment: that's just the way it works in JS, you have to spell out the case for each 'or' or ||.

Comment: One possible shortcut is `(name.charCodeAt(0) % 32) === 10`, where `10` represents either "J" or "j" as the tenth letter in the alphabet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`toLowerCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) :

```
function doesItStartWithJ (name) {
    //Will cover "J" and "j"
    if(name.charAt(0).toLowerCase() === "j") {
        return "Hello " + name + "!";
    } else {
        return "Who are you?";
    }
}
```